# How do I use the radio operator?

Tags: men-of-war

While playing the single player USA mission "Philippines" I encountered an issue. I fielded a radio operator that cost 400MP (quite a lot for defense) but I didn't seem to understand how it works.

I thought it would call in off map artillery or naval fire support but I couldn't figure out how to do anything with it. There are no extra options like "call in X support", there are only the normal infantry actions.

**How do you use the radio operator, and what do they do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I was going to post just the question, but I became distracted before I did. I decided to investigate more and I found the answer.*

The radio operator has an [artillery signal gun](http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/558721446800269164/52319BED6FAF47BF8A26944C06756D1C14B94C08/) as his secondary weapon, and [artillery signal ammo](http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/558721446800262832/26715CE28F3F52DAE0F9947B5C9B6A46D52A25EB/) in his inventory (the big box). If you select it and go into "direct control mode" (hotkey '*e*'), you can shoot [awesome pink smoke signals](http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/558721446800273076/9617DD89A13C8C4D24FF6FDD9CD34185D02D2A0F/). After a short time, off-map artillery will rain explosions at a 1:1 ratio for each signal shot you fired.

Suggestion: Danger close is a [bad idea](http://cloud.steampowered.com/ugc/558721446800278174/6204969315D79BD3D04D7E8C95587CFAF3292FBE/).